# Consecutive update requests in JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, concurrency, jparepository

I have a table "message". In this table there is column message_seen boolean. In my application i have chat, and when user_1 have dialog page opened with user_2 i need to set all incoming messages as message_seen: true.

So i have a request within JPA repository:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Message m SET m.message_seen = true WHERE m.message_id = :messageId")
void setMessageSeen(@Param("messageId") Long messageId);
```

and in controller i call it (i recieve messages by STOMP)

```
@Transactional
@MessageMapping("/setSeen")
public void setSeen(Map<String, Integer> messageIdObj){
  System.out.println(messageIdObj.get("messageId"))
  messageRepository.setMessageSeen(messageIdObj.get("messageId"));
}
```

But when i make requests one by one in a short time interval (about  one second or two)
in console i see all messageId i have sent,
but not all messages in table (I'm using postgresql db) have field "message_seen" set to true, If i make interval between sending messages longer everything works properly. What is the reason of this behaviour? Is this related to concurrency and how i can fix it?

ChatGPT3 did not help me, it offers to add

`@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`

but it didn't work for me
here is Message class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private Integer messageId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_user", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User fromUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "to_user", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User toUser;

    @Column(name = "message_text", nullable = false)
    private String messageText;

    @Column(name = "sent_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime sentDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friendship_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Friendship friendship;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name="message_seen")
    private Boolean messageSeen;


//constructor, getters, setters
```

this is message repository

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Integer> {

    List<Message> findByFriendshipId(int friendshipId);

    @Query("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.toUser.id = :toUser AND m.messageSeen = false")
    List<Message> findUnreadMessagesByToUser(@Param("toUser") Integer toUser);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Message m SET m.messageSeen = true WHERE m.messageId = :messageId")
    void setMessageSeen(@Param("messageId") Integer messageId);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an exception thrown in the console? Could you also provide the code of your Message class?

Comment: in console there are no exceptions, and some of messages sent set to status message_seen: true but some are not.
Added Class Message to question

Answer (score 0):

the issue was resolved by change method setSeen from recieving messages with STOMP ( @MessageMapping("/setSeen")) to simple @PostMapping("/setSeen) so it was some problem with STOMP, but what was that problem still a question...